# How to sort strings in Scala with complex criteria?

Tags: scala, sorting

There is a list of Strings in Scala. For example:

```
val l1 = List("bb", "c", "ddd", "a", "dbac", "aa", "d", "abcd")
```

Sorting it by length is easy:

```
l1.sortWith( _.length < _.length)
```

But it gives following result:

```
List(c, a, d, bb, aa, ddd, dbac, abcd)
```

But how can I add secondary sorting parameter? I want elements of the same length sorted alphabetically. So the result should be:

```
List(a, c, d, bb, aa, ddd, abcd, dbac)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
l1.sortBy(p => (p.length, p)) //> res0: List[String] = List(a, c, d, aa, bb, ddd, abcd, dbac)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sorting by multiple fields. Length + String itself

```
  val l = List("bb", "c", "ddd", "a", "dbac", "aa", "d", "abcd")

  val ord = Ordering.by((s: String) => (s.length, s))

  println(l.sorted(ord))
```